# Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory

Tags: classpath, tridion, dd4t

I am implementing DD4T MVC3 with  Tridion 2011. I have implemented it and it worked properly till last Friday. I am able to get the page model and present it using Razor view.

But today after the weekend when I tried to run the same application I am getting the below error (starting after two lines).

The Tridion license is going to expire today (30-Apr-2012). Will that be a problem? But the Tridion Content Manager is working properly.

```
Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
================================================

Some configured classpath roots cannot be found

================================================

   ClassPath           : C:\MyProjects\DD4TMVC\FirstDD4TMVCApplication\FirstDD4TMVCApplication\bin\bin

============================================================
Some Java classes or interfaces could not be found or loaded

The most typical reasons for this problem are:

- you forgot to configure a classpath
- a jarfile, zipfile, or directory is missing from your
  classpath
- you have a typo in one of your classpath entries
- a jarfile required by one of your classes is missing from
  your classpath
- a jarfile on your classpath is out-of-date and does not
  contain some new classes

============================================================

 com.tridion.web.asp.ASPAdmin
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.DynamicComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.IncrementKeyHandler
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataPublicationMappingFilter
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.ResponseWrapper
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ConditionsHandler
 com.tridion.linking.Linking
 com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.ComponentPresentationHandler
 com.tridion.web.Admin
 com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataContextListener
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPProcessor
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TargetGroupHandler
 com.tridion.linking.ASPLinking
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.BinaryLinkHandler
 com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter
 com.tridion.webservices.security.authentication.OAuth2AccessTokenHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPXSLTProcessor
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.PageLinkHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.TaxonomyHandler
 com.tridion.web.jsp.tag.LinkBaseHandler
```

Please help

Comment: If your license will expire today and something stopped working (while nothing else changed), there is a good chance that the two events are indeed related. I suggest you first get an updated license and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I think the date you can read in the cd_licenses.xml is the date at which the license expires, not the last day it still works. The Tridion logs will let you know this for sure.

Comment: after updating the license the application started working normal. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Dunno why this Q got downvoted: Tridion way of saying "your license went to hell" is mileading at best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you get a new SDL Tridion Content Delivery license first, and if you still have the problem get back to us. That seems like the a likely culprit.

Comment: Indeed, I had the very same problem 2 weeks ago and solved it by installing a valid cd_licenses.xml.

Comment: after updating the license the application started working normal. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

We resolved the similar issue by replacing license file only.

Thanks,
Vikas Kumar

Comment: after updating the license the application started working normal. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

**IF** changing the license doesn't help, then check the logs for `ClassDefNotFound` error or `ClassNotFoundException` exception. The Core log or Tridion event log are very good candidates to contain these errors.

Comment: after updating the license the application started working normal. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not the license as mentioned above, make sure that all of settings in the storage configuration file cd_storage_conf.xml are valid. I saw this same error when  was missing database information.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed an expired cd_licenses will cause this issue.

What i saw today is this:

```
ERROR - <JavaException  <Type>java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError</Type<Message>     <![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
================================================ 
Some configured classpath roots cannot be found
================================================
```

So Perfect solution is to change cd_licenses file with nice validity.

Comment: ahh ! Added this error header with the reference to the error above, i have just pasted header so that we can identify the same issue type.